# How to show the user their automatically generated password after social login?

Tags: wordpress, passwords, facebook-login, password-protection, change-password

I am faced with a beautiful enigma. In wordpress I have a widget that allows you to login with social login (google and facebook). When you login for the first time, the system automatically generates a password and username. This works well. I checked the database and password is correctly present as hashed.

Now, the problem is that if the user goes into profile settings and wants to change their password they have to enter current password first, but they can't know it since it was generated automatically.

I would like to give the user full control over the security of his account, so that he can change his password even if he is logged in with the social login.

So I foresee three possible solutions

1. Allow the password to be changed without entering the current one (but it seems insecure).
2. Email the automatically generated password (and I have no idea how I could do it). Or alternatively view it in the user's profile but I don't know how safe it is.
3. Disable social login and rely on the classic registration :)

Has anyone faced a similar situation before? Can you clarify this with some standard method / practice ?

Comment: 4) Leave things as is, and include a "Forgot Password?" link so they can reset it via email?

Comment: I already have this feature, but I still wanted to give the user the ability to do it in their account settings. I don't know how usual it is, but I think it's more immediate and convenient ...

Comment: Another thing you could do with #2 is include a password reset link with the email so the user has the option of changing the automatically generated password as soon as they register their account. Of course, this means you'd need to figure out how to send such an email notification first in which case you may need to contact the developer of the social plugin to get some help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow the user to ask for a new password he/she specifies. The user will specify the password twice (password and confirm password fields) and then you:

- encrypt the password the user asked for
- store the encrypted value somewhere as password candidate (metadata, perhaps)
- send an email to the user so he/she can confirm that he/she indeed asked for a password
- once the user clicks on the link you have sent to him/her, replace the value of the password with the password candidate and remove the password candidate

Don't forget that the user is already logged in when he/she changes his/her password, adding an email validation to the password he/she asked for is pretty safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not do exactly what you described but I created a condition whereby if the user is logged in with social login, then instead of showing the classic password change form, I show the reset link for the password. The advantage is that I haven't touched any files but just played around with the if else conditions.

Comment: @Snorlax happy to help! Basically if you are satisfied with your current solution, then the task is completed. It is not unsafe, but it could be safer if you intend to increase safety. Your approach assumes that the user whose password is to be changed is the same person as the one who used the same social network credentials to create the user. The edge-case is when I register to your site with a Facebook account and then somehow my account gets hacked and someone impersonates me. In that case your approach will not detect a problem and the hacker will steal this identity as well from the...

Comment: @Snorlax ... victim. The reason for my suggestion is that it identifies the person by his/her social network identity and his/her email as well during the process, so it is safer. Yet, I recognize that this kind of increase in safety would mean more implementation time as well as less comfortable password change for a user. So, it is up to you to determine how sensitive an account is and whether it is worth the trouble to even improve security. You may decide for or against it, depending on your project and goals.